# How to fetch Sleep data from Google's REST api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-fit

I'm trying to fetch my sleep data from Google-Fit.

When I make the following request -

```js
const { data: sleepData } = await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
        data: {
          aggregateBy: [{ dataTypeName: 'com.google.sleep.segment' }],
          bucketByTime: { durationMillis: 86400000 },
          startTimeMillis: startTimeQuery, // day start time in UNIX
          endTimeMillis: endTimeQuery, // day end time in UNIX
        },
      });
```

I'm getting the following data with empty points -

```json
      {
        "bucket": [
          {
            "startTimeMillis": "1651115600000",
            "endTimeMillis": "1651202000000",
            "dataset": [
              {
                "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.sleep.segment:com.google.android.gms:merged",
                "point": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "startTimeMillis": "1651202000000",
            "endTimeMillis": "1651288400000",
            "dataset": [
              {
                "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.sleep.segment:com.google.android.gms:merged",
                "point": []
              }
            ]
          },
       ]}
```

Has anyone run into similar problems?

I'm using Google-Fit on an Android Device.

Comment: The process of authenticating requests to the service requires the use of GCP. I will not remove the tag.

Comment: The fitness API is part of google-cloud https://console.cloud.google.com/tos?id=fitness. 
It's required to be enabled in the console before use. You must generate OAuth client IDs, handle scopes, etc in order to use the API. This is done through GCP. 

I've reported both of your comments as they are unnecessary. 

Please keep comments constructive and relative to the topic at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Hey here is a working example from Google Fitness REST API with my account which is connected to my sleep tracking device.

```
var axios = require('axios');
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "aggregateBy": [
    {
      "dataTypeName": "com.google.sleep.segment"
    }
  ],
  "endTimeMillis": {endTimeMillis},
  "startTimeMillis": {startTimeMillis}
});

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {AccessToken}', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

The Only difference is to remove the **bucketByTime** so that Fitness API will send the segment points as small as possible.